# Total number of non-congruent scalene triangles?

Tags: geometry

What is the number of non-congruent scalene triangles whose sides all have integral length, and the longest side has length 11?

What does it mean by non-congruent scalene triangles? Do we have to use Pythagoras' Theorem and use trial-and-error for each integer until 11?

Comment: [..]the method of hit-and-trial or the famous trial-and-error is being referred here.

Comment: @kannappan ya.i am sorry.its trial and error.

Answer (score 4):

A triangle is *scalene* if all sides have different lengths.

You will not need the Pythagorean Theorem. You *will* need the fact that three positive numbers are the sides of a triangle if and only if the sum of any two is greater than the third. This is called the *Triangle Inequality*.

You will need the fact that two triangles are congruent if and only if they have the same side lengths.

There is general theory, but just try to make a complete list, by being very systematic. The longest side is $11$.  There is no other side of length $11$, since the triangle is scalene, and in particular not isosceles. So the biggest candidate for second longest side is $10$.

How many scalene triangles have second longest side equal to $10$? To list and count, what are the possibilities for the smallest side? Can you see it is anything from $2$ to $9$, inclusive?

How many of our triangles have second longest side equal to $9$?  Continue.  It is easy to make a mistake, so make full explicit lists. **Shortcuts** come later!

**Remark:** If you work through this example systematically, you can learn enough to tackle similar problems without much trouble.

Let's introduce some notation. List the sides of the triangle as $(a,b,c)$, where $a>b>c$ (we can't have equality anywhere, since we are looking for scalene triangles.) In our case we have $a=11$, so we only care about the pair $(b,c)$.

A useful fact is that automatically we have $a+b>c$ and $a+c>b$. So for the Triangle Inequality, we only need to make sure that $b+c>a$.

Comment: Can you please give an example by taking largest side=10.I am not able to get your answer totally , thats why needs some more explaination.

Comment: @vikiiii: You mean **second** largest side $10$, the largest is $11$. So for second largest side $10$, the smallest side is any of $9$, $8$, $7$, $6$, $5$, $4$, $3$, $2$ (eight possibilities). For second largest side $9$, smallest is any of $8$, $7$, $6$, $5$, $4$, $3$ (six possibilities). For second largest side $8$, smallest is any of $7$, $6$, $5$, $4$. For second largest side $7$, smallest is any of $6$, $5$. For second largest $6$ or below, there are no triangles. Add up.